What antivirus program am I using?
I thought I was using Windows Defender on my Windows 10 laptop.
I tried checking the Security and Maintenance panel as well as the Virus & threat protection panel.
Neither show the name of the AV.

How can I query the system for an explicit answer of what AV is running?
Afternote:
If I right-click a file in Windows Explorer, the context menu provides the option to scan using Windows Defender.
From the past, however, I recall that some of the options can be obsolete.
I'm now pretty sure that my AV is Windows Defender, but I'm wondering if there is a surer way to confirm this.

You are indeed using Windows Defender which is the default built-in antivirus in Windows 10.
If you had Windows Defender turned off (it's on by default) then the Windows Security page would tell you that it's off. And if you would have a 3rd party AV, it would show you the name of that AV. So the fact that Windows Security simply shows you're protected means that you're running Windows Defender.
If you still for some reason want to get it as an actual text written output, you can query the system in command line using the following command to get your active antivirus:
wmic /node:localhost /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct Get DisplayName | findstr /V /B /C:displayName || echo No Antivirus installed
